# How to find multifactorials $ n\underbrace{!!\ldots !}_m$ in Wolframalpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I heed to compute $ n\underbrace{!!\ldots !}_m$.

The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) is $ n\underbrace{!!\ldots !}_m = \prod_{i=1}^{k}(mi-r)$, $n=3m-r$, $k \in Z$, $r \in \{0,1,\ldots, m-1\}$.

**Question.** Is it exist a *short* formula in Wolframalpha to find, for example, $3!!!$?

I have tried:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((3!)!)!)

Comment: I don't understand what you are searching for, are you searching for the algorithm Wolframalpha uses?

Comment: try to use [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html)

Comment: It appears that Wolfram only explicitly allows for double factorials, which can be used with factorial2[x] or double factorial x.